# Python: Converting a list of sets to a set

Tags: python, list, set, dfa

I am working on a programming project involving DFAs, and I've come across an error I can't seem to figure out how to bypass.

In this section of code:

```
from DFA import *

def DAWG():
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                'y', 'z']
    f = open('lexicontest.txt', 'r')
    dictionary = list(f)
    accepts = []
    for i in dictionary:
        if len(i) >= 3:
            accepts.append(i)
    D = from_word_list(accepts, alphabet)
    newStates = frozenset(D.mn_classes())
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "...\DAWG.py", line 31, in <module>
DAWG()
  File "...\DAWG.py", line 19, in DAWG
newStates = frozenset(D.mn_classes())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

This is because the method mn_classes() returns a list whose elements are sets. I am looking for a way to convert this list into a set, but I cannot do so right now because sets must be hashable. If anyone could give me advice on how to convert this list into a set, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a DFA library designed by Andrew Badr found [here](https://github.com/reverie/python-automata) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-automata/). This is the code for the method mn_classes():

```
def mn_classes(self):
    """Returns a partition of self.states into Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes."""
    changed = True
    classes = []
    if self.accepts != []:
        classes.append(self.accepts)
    #nonaccepts = filter(lambda x: x not in self.accepts, self.states)
    nonaccepts = [x for x in self.states if x not in self.accepts]
    if nonaccepts != []:
        classes.append(str(nonaccepts))
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for cl in classes:
            local_change = False
            for alpha in self.alphabet:
                next_class = None
                new_class = []
                for state in cl:
                    next = self.delta(state, alpha)
                    if next_class == None:
                        for c in classes:
                            if next in c:
                                next_class = c
                    elif next not in next_class:
                        new_class.append(state)
                        changed = True
                        local_change = True
                if local_change == True:
                    old_class = []
                    for c in cl:
                        if c not in new_class:
                            old_class.append(c)
                    classes.remove(cl)
                    classes.append(old_class)
                    classes.append(new_class)
                    break
    return classes
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the list of sets into a set of sets or into a set of whatever the elements of the sets in the list are?

Comment: What are you doing with the set? If you're just checking for redundancy, you can write any custom hashing function you want and then add the hashed results to the set.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use `from x import *` unless you really need to. It creates ambiguity and potentially causes name collisions while offering no real benefit in most situations.

Comment: @jwodder: I would like to use the list as a set of sets, so that I can create a new DFA with each state being a set of states. This DFA implementation stores the states as a set, so I would need a set of sets to create a new DFA.

Comment: @TimWilder: I am trying to use the set to create a new DFA whose states are each sets of other states. 
And as for your suggestion, how else would I import all the information from the DFA.py file? I am fairly new to using Python so I apologize for any foolish errors in my code like that one.

Comment: Instead do `import DFA`, then reference things as `DFA.function_name` (this is general preferred as it offers the most clarity). In some cases, one example being where the name of something might be too long to be convenient, `from DFA.sub_package.sub_sub_package import function_name` is also fine. There's a few other things like aliasing that can be done, but basically `import module_name` should be your bread and butter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mn_class` code looks suspicious to me, especially `classes.append(str(nonaccepts))` seems not to be a set in a list. Followint part is also dubious:

```
if next_class == None:
    for c in classes:
        if next in c:
            next_class = c
```

Answering the quesition your asked, "If anyone could give me advice on how to convert this list into a set" modulo "mn_classes() returns a list whose elements are sets" you can use `DAWG` approach, i.e. return list of frozensets in `mn_classes`:

```
return map(frosenset, classes)
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you about the validity of the `mn_class` code as I did not write this library and have not used it before attempting to use it on this project. I wish I understood it all better but I am basically winging it.

I tried your suggestion of using `return map(frozenset, classes)` and was met with the error `File "...\DAWG.py", line 22, in delta
    next = q+c
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'frozenset' and 'str'`

when it was doing the `pretty_print` function.

Comment: And this was after I added this code to the bottom of the program:
    `D = from_word_list(accepts, alphabet)
    newStates = set(D.mn_classes())
    #D.pretty_print()
    def delta(q, c):
        next = q+c
        if next in fwl:
            return next
        else:
            return sink
    N = DFA(newStates, alphabet, delta, '', accepts)
    N.pretty_print()`